# How to revert the results of gsettings set org.gnome.desktop command

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I try to change the theme of my Ubuntu 18.04 how it is described [here](http://omgfoss.com/install-sierra-gtk-theme-ubuntu/)

after commands

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "macOS High Sierra"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "macOS High Sierra"
```

I have the result, which I don't like.

**Could you help me to revert changes?**

Comment: Have you not installed Gnome Tweaks?

Comment: I installed it before this commands

Comment: Simply you can select default themes from drop drown under Appearence tab selections

Comment: But terminal is still white

Comment: Logout and login

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `gsettings` command has various subcommands:

```
pduck@host > gsettings
Usage:
  gsettings --version
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] COMMAND [ARGS…]

Commands:
  help                      Show this information
  list-schemas              List installed schemas
  list-relocatable-schemas  List relocatable schemas
  list-keys                 List keys in a schema
  list-children             List children of a schema
  list-recursively          List keys and values, recursively
  range                     Queries the range of a key
  describe                  Queries the description of a key
  get                       Get the value of a key
  set                       Set the value of a key
  reset                     Reset the value of a key
  reset-recursively         Reset all values in a given schema
  writable                  Check if a key is writable
  monitor                   Watch for changes

Use “gsettings help COMMAND” to get detailed help.
```

... and especially the `reset` subcommand:

```
pduck@host > gsettings help reset
Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] reset SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY

Reset KEY to its default value
...
```

So:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme
```

---

Personal observation: I never changed my theme or icon pack 
and `gsettings get …` shows `'Ambiance'` for both.

But apparently this is not the default, because when I 
`gsettings reset …` them, then I get `'Ambiance'` 
for the `gtk-theme` and `'Adwaita'` for the `theme`.
I've set them both back to `'Ambiance'`.

Comment: Indeed distributions can set gsettings overrides. This does not change the default setting, but sets an alternative gsettings value on a clean install.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That's what I thought. So it is always advisable to do a `gsettings get …` before fiddling around with the values. I did so before I tried the `reset` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

**Reset Icon Pack**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ''
```

**Reset Theme**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''
```

After run this command logout and login back or reboot.